# Dependency injection does not work if Autofac.Extras.Quartz is used

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, quartz.net

**Description**

I read a lot how to configure Autofac.Extras.Quartz to add Autofac integration, but it simply does not work, I struggle with such issues:

1. Dependency injection via constructor does not work (but if I add parameterless constructor - it is called)
2. Last registered job is only called, triggers which added before last job - never fired

I spent a lot of time to figure out how to start it properly (which looks simple but not workable in my case), the most relevant to my case [closed issue](https://github.com/alphacloud/Autofac.Extras.Quartz/issues/8) of project where people had the same issues, but going through it did not help.
Any help is appreciated.

**Code:**

```c#
...
// Configure Autofac
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
...
builder.RegisterModule<AutofacRepositoryModule>(); // registration of repositores
...
builder.RegisterModule(new QuartzAutofacFactoryModule());
builder.RegisterModule(new QuartzAutofacJobsModule(typeof(ConvertOrdersJob).Assembly));
builder.RegisterType<JobScheduler>().AsSelf();
var container = builder.Build();
ConfigureScheduler(container);
config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
...

private static void ConfigureScheduler(IContainer container)
{
    var scheduler = container.Resolve<JobScheduler>();
    scheduler.Start();
}
```

Registration of repositories in AutofacRepositoryModule:

```c#
public class AutofacRepositoryModule : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        ...
        builder.RegisterType<DumpReportRepository>().As<IDumpReportRepository>();
        ...
    }
}
```

Configure jobs:

```c#
public class JobScheduler
{
    private IScheduler _scheduler;

    public JobScheduler(IScheduler scheduler)
    {
        _scheduler = scheduler;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        // BUG1: Find out why cleanupDumpsTrigger never fired
        // BUG2: Dependency injection via constructor does not work
        var cleanupDumpsJob = JobBuilder.Create<DumpsCleanupJob>().Build();
        var cleanupDumpsTrigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithIdentity("CleanupDumpsTrigger", "dumps")
            .StartNow()
            .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
                .WithIntervalInHours(24)
                .RepeatForever())
            .Build();
        _scheduler.ScheduleJob(cleanupDumpsJob, cleanupDumpsTrigger);

        var convertOrdersJob = JobBuilder.Create<ConvertOrdersJob>().Build();
        var convertOrdersTrigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithIdentity("ConvertOrdersTrigger", "orders")
            .StartNow()
            .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
                .WithIntervalInHours(1)
                .RepeatForever())
            .Build();
        _scheduler.ScheduleJob(convertOrdersJob, convertOrdersTrigger);

        _scheduler.Start();
    }
```

Example of job:

```c#
[DisallowConcurrentExecution]
public class DumpsCleanupJob : IJob
{
    private readonly IDumpReportRepository _dumpReportRepository;
    public DumpsCleanupJob(IDumpReportRepository dumpReportRepository)
    {
       // BUG: Constructor is never called  
        _dumpReportRepository = dumpReportRepository;
    }
    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            ...
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

**Versions:**

I tried bunch of versions of Quartz (2.x-3.x)/Autofac.Extras.Quartz (3.x-4.0.0)

**Workaround**

Temporary solution:

1. Usage of Autofac.Extras.Quartz was removed
2. All dependencies are simply created in parameterless constructor
3. Default scheduler is used `_scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler()` to configure all jobs (which all are started correctly)

If package does not work, then custom AutofacJobFactory will be implemented.

Comment: There is no `IDumpReportRepository` component registration to DI container in provided code and Autofac doesn't automatically scan assemblies for type registration.  Do you have something like `builder.RegisterInstance(new DumpReportRepository()).As<IDumpReportRepository >();`   or via assembly scan: `builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(yourAssembly) .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Repository")).AsImplementedInterfaces();` ?

Comment: Thanks you, I updated the code(showing repository registration) @Set

Comment: Did you try something like this - https://davidsekar.com/asp-net/scheduling-using-quartz-net-with-autofac-di

Comment: Do you still have this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to create jobs with custom IJobFactory.

```
scheduler.JobFactory = new JobFactoryInjection(container);
```